# how to delete first 50 directories within a directory linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking to run a script which moves 50 directories to a new directory, once it has carried out that action it then deletes those 50 from the original directory

I have the below so far in my bash script:

```
cd /folder1/subfolder1/directories

mv `ls | head -50` ../subfolder2/
```

Comment: What's the problem with your script? Looks like it should do what you want? Any errors? Usually people recommend not to parse `ls` output, so you could replace that with `find . -type d`, which also makes sure you only get directories, not files.

Comment: Is your path correct? You're cd-ing into /folder1/subfolder1/directories/ and then copying the first 50 items (whether directories or not) into /folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/. Based on how you named these folders, perhaps the target is meant to be /folder1/subfolder2/ ?

Comment: Don't use `ls` to get filenames.

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash?

Answer (score 5):

```bash
cd /folder1/subfolder1/directories
dirs=( ./*/ )                            # an array of directories
mv -t ../subfolder2/ "${dirs[@]:0:50}"   # first 50 array elements
```

For GNU coreutils `mv`, `-t` is the "target" (aka, destination) directory. This can be very handy if there are hundreds/thousands of files to move (more than can fit in one command):

```bash
some-process-that-produces-filenames-on-stdout | xargs mv -t dest_dir/
```

Comment: Also, [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I think this would do as well with `printf %s\\0 ./*/ | xargs -0n50 mv -t -- ../subfolder2/`